# JPA Hibernate MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping

I have createa simple CRUD application utilize JPA and Hibernate.

I have entity annotated JPA `javax.persistence.@entity` annotation and hibernate configuration file `(hibernate.cfg.xml)`.

I do not use the JPA entity manager rather than using the Hibernate Native API `(Session, Session Factory, HibernateUtil)`.
I do not have hibernate mapping file and `persistence.xml`.

Any problem.

Please help.

Comment: Specify the table name to your mapping annotation - and see if it works.

Comment: I have @Table(name = "TableName") and the mapping exception is still raise.

Comment: I using Hibernate Native API and there is no auto discovery entity class. Thus, i just specified the mapping in hibermate.cfg.xml and it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to have mapping file as you are using JPA annotations. But certainly you have to have persistence.xml unless if you are using Spring 3.1 LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean class.

Comment: Should i create the persistence.xml and include the provider that i use. Please give me example of the persistence.xml

Comment: You can find one from this link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging

Comment: I have create the persistence.xml but still getting the mappingException.

Comment: I would like to use JPA for mapping and Hibernate as provider.